# Bloom Filter hash is returning far too many collisions

Tags: javascript, node.js, algorithm, ecmascript-6, bloom-filter

I have been trying to implement my own (simple) Bloom Filter but am stuck on hashing, I understand the concept of hashing the item multiple times and populating the bit array with the indices.

However, I am seeing a ton of collisions in my hashing, I am using 1 hash algorithm (I have tried FNV, murmurhash and now farmhash) with various seeds (based on current nanoseconds).

I must be doing something wrong, I am calculating the `k` functions by following the [information here](https://corte.si/posts/code/bloom-filter-rules-of-thumb/index.html) and setting the same amount of seeds.

Any help would be great, thanks.

```js
const farmhash = require('farmhash');

class BloomFilter {
 constructor(items, input)
 {
  const BITS_PER_ITEM = 15; //~0.1% false positive rate
  this.m = Buffer.alloc(items.length * BITS_PER_ITEM); // setup bit array
  this.k = Math.ceil(BITS_PER_ITEM * 0.7); // amount of hash functions we need to use
  this.seeds = [];
  this.input = input;
  this.items = items;

  this.setSeeds();
  this.insertItems();
 }

 get time()
 {
  let hrTime = process.hrtime()
  return hrTime[1];
 }

 setSeeds()
 {
  for(let i = 0; i <= this.k; i++) this.seeds.push(this.time);
 }
 
 insertItems()
 {
  console.log('Total buffer size: ' + this.m.length);

  let collisions = 0;
  this.items.forEach(value => {   
   this.getBufferIndices(value).map(index => {
    if(this.m[index] === 1) collisions++;
    this.m[index] = 1;
   });
  });

  console.log('Total collisions: ' + collisions);
 }

 getBufferIndices(value)
 {
  let indicies = [];

  this.seeds.forEach(seed => indicies.push(farmhash.hash32WithSeed(value, seed) % this.m.length));

  return indicies;
 }
}

module.exports = BloomFilter;
```

Comment: Please post the code in your question, not just a link to the current version.

Comment: @Bergi My bad, fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I remember from Bloom filters, a collision happens when *all* `k` indexes for a particular value match those of a different value.

It looks like you count a *single* bucket (`this.m[index]`) having been set previously as a collision.

The following (untested) code should count the actual collisions:

```
let collisions = 0;

this.items.forEach(value => {           
  let overlap = 0;
  this.getBufferIndices(value).map(index => {
    if(this.m[index] === 1) overlap++;
    this.m[index] = 1;
  });
  if (overlap === this.k) collisions++;
});
```

As @Thomas rightfully points out in his comment, instead of using `.map()` (which creates a new array), you should use `.forEach()`:

```
this.getBufferIndices(value).forEach(index, ...);
```

And in `getBufferIndices()`, you can use `.map()` instead of `.forEach()`:

```
getBufferIndices(value) {
  return this.seeds.map(seed => (farmhash.hash32WithSeed(value, seed) % this.m.length));
}
```

Comment: @Connor please don't use `Array#map` to do a `forEach`'s job, or maybe `reduce`. This creates an unnecessary Array wich only allocates memory and has to be GC. You don't deal with small Arrays here.

Comment: @robertklep of course, thank you very much - case of looking at the code too much I think.

Comment: @Thomas thanks, forgot to change it after refactoring